# is there any calculator in software centre which could solve quadratic equations?

Tags: software-recommendation

I want good scientific calculator which can calculate the roots of any quadratic equation just by entering the quadratic equation

first of all is any app like those there in ubuntu software centre??

Comment: Have you tried Scilab or Octave?

Comment: no i never heard those names but i will surely search them in  software centre now

Comment: Just see at their own official sites: http://www.scilab.org/ and http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/.

Comment: @AdeMalsasaAkbar does scilab uses terminal command as a new pop up window appeared after installation and the window was of terminal.. so my question is do we need to handle this app with termianl only

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's very simple in `octave`, just by entering the coefficients of the equation into the `roots` function

```
octave:1> roots([1,0,-1])
ans =

  -1
   1
```

See the online help

```
octave:2> help roots
 'roots' is a function from the file /usr/share/octave/3.8.1/m/polynomial/roots.m

 -- Function File: roots (V)

     For a vector V with N components, return the roots of the
     polynomial

          v(1) * z^(N-1) + ... + v(N-1) * z + v(N)

     As an example, the following code finds the roots of the quadratic
     polynomial

          p(x) = x^2 - 5.

          c = [1, 0, -5];
          roots (c)
          =>  2.2361
          => -2.2361

     Note that the true result is +/- sqrt(5) which is roughly +/-
     2.2361.

     See also: poly, compan, fzero.
```

Answer (score 2):

*Qalculate!* might fit your needs:

[image]